# Get Cell's Row number using EPPlus

Tags: c#, vb.net, epplus

How can I find the row numer of a specific cell using the EPPLus library?

I'm looking for a method along the lines of `Cl.Row`, but am not seeming to find it - Do I have to use the `cl.Address` and parse the row number out myself??

I'm sure this is a stupid Newbie question, but I can't seem to find the correct method.

Thanks!

Comment: From my experience, yes - the address is the only way to parse the row number. However, I've only used EPPlus once so far, someone with more experience may know a better way. You could create a struct to contain the row + a count...just an idea.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The cell is an `ExcelRange`, this has `Start` and `End` properties. If you want to know the row of the start of the  range:

```
Dim row As Int32 = cell.Start.Row
```

Comment: Tim, PERFECT!!! - Thank you so much! - Just waiting out the clock until I can accept your solution. Thanks!!!